# Enable Xray of teammates in competitive

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

Is there any way to see teammates through walls in competitive mode, or enable teammate X-ray, rather than having to use the mini-map? If there is a way to also do this with spotted enemies, this would be helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of March 15th 2017 there is now a way to accomplish what you are trying to do.

Valve added a new command: [cl_show_team_equipment](http://images.akamai.steamusercontent.com/ugc/90475659381456515/DDE01C40AC71869DC8F21D9EE99136EAF1732298/), which will show your teammates name, health percentage, and weapon/item inventory above their heads. This shows up through walls so, although it does not provide an exact outline like spectator mode does, it will show you their positioning at a glance which should fit your desires. You are able to set this command up as a toggle so that it'll only refresh/be on whenever you desire.

It does not work on enemies for obvious reasons.

Answer (score 2):

Apart from using hacks, there is no facility to allow for this, and I doubt there would ever be.

Depending on your style of play you can have the radar VERY zoomed IN or very zoomed out to kinda help you out.

I have it very zoomed out and see the entire map all the time. This helps me know where an enemy has been spotted and where all my teammates are, I can then make an educated guess - where they are going/will be based on direction etc.

You can have it VERY zoomed in and you'll be able to see where the enemy is actually looking at AND where they are around you. This is extra helpful when inside a smoke or hiding and having friendlies with you.